# SwiftUI SegmentedPickerStyle width proportional to Text length

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a Segmented Control with width proportional to the length of the text. My current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedElement = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Some choice").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Spacer()
                Picker("aaa", selection: $selectedElement, content: {
                    Text("choice 1").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    Text("another choice").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                })
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(16)
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Building this code results in:
[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Pjm.png)

What I would like to see is:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swTnV.png) where red rectangles show how much space each part should take. How can I achieve this ? Also, why does the `.foregroundColor(Color.black)` has no effect on the Text color within the Segmented Control ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, add .fixedSize() after your picker:

```
Picker("aaa", selection: $selectedElement, content: {
                Text("choice 1").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Text("another choice").foregroundColor(Color.black)
}).fixedSize()
```